# get members value, name and custom name from enum type with its name

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reflection, enums

i want to get a string from user and show him a list of enums member and its value.
for example i have this enum

```
public enum exampleEnum
    {
        [MyCustomProperty(customName = "نام1")]
        member1 = 1,

        [MyCustomProperty(customName = "نام2")]
        member2 = 2,

    }
```

help me for create this function

```
public List<enumResult> GetEnumDetailWithName(string enumName)
{
 ???

 return result;// {name:'member1',value:1,customName='نام1'},{name:'member2',value:2,customName='نام2'}
}
```

i have write this code but not complete
in this lines get enum from all assembly and its done 
then get all members of enum currectly
then for any member of enum add a member to result list , filling name is true but i cant fill Value and CustomName Field ...

```
     public List<enumDetail> GetEnumDetailWithName(string enumName)
    {
        var enumFullName = $"Bamdad.PublicEnum.Enums+{enumName}";
        var assemblyList = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        Type type = null;
        foreach (var assembly in assemblyList)
        {
            type = assembly.GetType(enumFullName);
            if (type == null)
                continue;
            if (type.IsEnum)
                break;
        }

        if (type == null)
            return null;


        //until this line get enum currectly
        var members = type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Where(q=> q?.DeclaringType?.Name == enumName).ToList();
        var properties = type.GetProperties();
        if (!members.Any()) return null;

        var result = new List<enumDetail>();

        //get members currectly
        foreach (var mem in members)
        {

            var resultItem =  new enumDetail()
            {
                Name = mem.Name, // true
                Value = 0,       // i cant get
                CustomName = "???" // i cant get
            };

            result.Add(resultItem);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this question i should use  Enum.GetValues and Enum.GetName , for getting custom attribute write a function and use it

```
    public List<enumDetail> GetEnumMemberFromString(string enumName)
    {
        var enumFullName = $"Bamdad.PublicEnum.Enums+{enumName}";
        var assemblyList = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        Type type = null;
        foreach (var assembly in assemblyList)
        {
            type = assembly.GetType(enumFullName);
            if (type == null)
                continue;
            if (type.IsEnum)
                break;
        }

        if (type == null) return null;

        var valuesToNames = Enum.GetValues(type)
                .Cast<object>()
                .ToDictionary(q => Enum.GetName(type, q),q=> (int)q);

        var result = valuesToNames.Select(q => new enumDetail()
        {
            Name = q.Key,
            Value = q.Value,
            CustomName = type.GetMyCustomProperty(q.Key)?.ToString() ?? q.Key
        }).ToList();

        return result;
    }
```

this function is for getting custom attribute

```
 public static object GetMyCustomProperty(this Type type,string member = "")
    {
        if (type == null)
            return "";
        MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(member);
        if (memInfo.Length <= 0) return member;

        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomPropertyAttribute), false);
        if (!attrs.Any())
            return null;

        var result = ((MyCustomPropertyAttribute)attrs[0]);

  return result.customName;

 }
```